# How should I include a file where of I know the path, but don't want to use ../?

Tags: php, include

I want to include a script that I can find in http://localhost/scripts/script.php , but there's something wrong, as we all know: the unclusion of a file using an url is not possible! How can I include a file in the file that's located in http://localhost/admin/employees/create.php?

I do not want to use things like

```
require_once('../../scripts/script.php');
// or, as that is impossible to do
require_once('http://localhost/scripts/script.php');
```

So, is there something that I can do so that the system starts from the homedirectory and doesn't interpret the PHP on beforehand?

Thanks in advance for the help you'll provide me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is using the following script:

```
<?php
$docroot = $_SERVER['document_root'];
require_once($docroot.'/scripts/script.php');
?>
```

Important! The server has to be well-configured for this method. At least the document_root should be set properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of info, look inside what´s the best for you, there are differences depending on OS of server:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Comment: I don't need the supberglobal, but the way how to include without any server name or similar things...